# C# Load Datatable from LinQ XDocument using Using XPath where Xpath not known at compile time

Tags: c#, xpath, datatable, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I have a LinQ XDocument (from a SOAP response) that I want to turn into a Datatable.  Here is the XML I am dealig with. It uses namespaces to further complicate the matter.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.xyz.com/">
            <return>
                <meeting meetingCode="8">
                    <meetingDate>2013-07-08T00:00:00+10:00</meetingDate>
                    <actionList>
                        <actionCoOrdinator>The action man</actionCoOrdinator>
                        <action>
                            <actionType>Type1</actionType>
                            <actionBy>John</actionBy>
                        </action>
                        <action>
                            <actionType>Type2</actionType>
                            <actionBy>Mary</actionBy>
                        </action>
                        <action>
                            <actionType>Type3</actionType>
                            <actionBy>Phil</actionBy>
                        </action>
                    </actionList>
                </meeting>
            </return>
        </ns2:getDetailsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is the output that want in a DataTable

```
    MeetingCode MeetingDate               ActionCoOrdinator ActionType ActionBy
    ----------- ------------------------- ----------------- ---------- --------
    8           2013-07-08T00:00:00+10:00 The action man    Type1      John
    8           2013-07-08T00:00:00+10:00 The action man    Type2      Mary
    8           2013-07-08T00:00:00+10:00 The action man    Type3      Phil
```

As you can see I want a row for each "action" element within "actionList" but for each row I also need some info from parent/grandparent elements.  All I have at this this stage is an XDocument using the code below;

```
XDocument myXDoc = XDocument.Parse(soapStringResult);
```

I've seen various posts about extracting data from an XDocument on this site but my problem is that the data items i want are not know beforehand.  My starting point is an xPath which represents the "rows".  The Xpath is

```
ns2:getDetailsResponse/return/meeting/actionList/action
```

Then i have a DB table that contains all the data items i want relative to this Xpath.  The table looks like this

```
    XpathDataItem
    ---------------------
    ../../@meetingCode
    ../../meetingDate
    ../actionCoOrdinator
    actionType
    actionBy
```

I can load the data into a DataTable when I know the Xpaths of the data items I'm looking for but I just dont know how to do it with an unknown set of XPaths's.

Thanks in advance
John

Answer (score 0):

Which part is unknown? The starting point or the individual elements to retrieve? That's not clear from your question. If you simply don't know the starting point, then Linq-to-xml will work great for this.

Linq-to-xml doesn't normally retrieve elements based on xpath. The `Elements()` and `Descendants()` methods allow you query the xml data without knowing the specific path.

To retrieve the `meetingDate` regardless of what its path is, you could use the `Descendants()` method like this:

```
var meetingDateElement = myXDoc.Descendants("meetingDate").SingleOrDefault;
if (meetingDateElement != null) {
    var meetingDate = meetingDateElement.Value;
}
```

`meetingCode` and `actionCoOrdinator` could be found in a similar manner.

And to get all the `action` elements, you'd simple use `myXDoc.Descendants("action")`. Something like this would get you the values for each action:

```
var actions = from a in myXDoc.Descendants("action")
              select new {
                             actionType = a.Element("actionType").Value,
                             actionBy = a.Element("actionBy").Value
                          };
```

If the xml you're parsing could contain more than one `meeting` element, then you'd use `myXDoc.Descendants("meeting") to get all the meetings and retrieve child elements within a query or foreach statement.